# Using ++*p++ in a c program gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *p1="khan",*p2;
    p2 = p1;

    while ( *p1 != '\0')
    {
        // printf("I am in while.\n");
        ++*p1++;
        // printf("I am after ++*p1++.\n");

        printf("%c\n",*p1 );
    }
    printf("%s %s\n", p1,p2);
}
```

The compilation of above code gives unexpected results:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here is what I am expecting:

```
++*p1++;
```

1. Post ++ has higher precedance: p1 = p1 + 1.
2. Now, p1 will point to the p1 -> h.
3. We have two operators here `++*`, * has higher precedance. So *p1 will be increased and we have value, *p1 = i;

Now, I should get "ki.." in p1. But, I am unable to iterate only once in while loop.

```
 printf("I am in while.\n");
   ++*p1++; //getting error here.
 printf("I am after ++*p1++.\n"); //this line is never called
```

Comment: The term "pre" and "post" actually not only refer to the position of the operator, but also to its semantics...

Comment: Is there a good reason to use such a construct? The only one I can see is academic (arguably).

Comment: but also to its semantics : I couldn't get it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah, this was the case.

Comment: Yes, so don't do it.  It's trash code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trash code of zero or negative use to future SO users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
++*p1++
```

is parsed as

```
(++ (* (p1 ++) ) )
```

and evaluated as follows:

1. `p1++` is evaluated; the result of the expression is the value of `p1` *before* the increment;
2. the result of 1 is dereferenced
3. the result of 2 is incremented
4. Somewhere between the end of 1 and now, `p1` is advanced to point to the next element.

You're getting the segfault because you're attempting to alter the contents of a *string literal*, which is not allowed.  Change your code to something like

```
char str[] = "khan";
char *p1 = str;
```

and it should work.  Note that your output will be `"libo"`, not `"kibo"`.

Comment: why you said and emphasise that output would be "libo " not "kibo" .Wouldn't be there undefined behaviour as more than one sideeffects is in single statement and on single variable.

Comment: @RaghibAhsan: there's no undefined behavior here; the postfix `++` is applied to the pointer, the prefix `++` is applied to what it *points to*.  We're not modifying the same object.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `'k'+1` is equal to 'l'.

Answer (score 2):

```
++*p1++;
```

is equal to

```
(++*(p1++));
```

which attempts to modify the string literal. Problem is:
**Modifying string literals is undefined behavior.**

Therefore `p1` should be a `const char*`, which is also strictly enforced in C++.

Try

```
char str[] = "khan";
char* p1 = str;
```

for example. This will store the string on the stack and not in some read-only section.

Comment: @EOF Yep, fixed. Have overlooked the corresponding line.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is undefined behaviour.

> ++*p++

We would have no way of knowing which order the two increments would happen in, and in fact the compiler wouldn't have any idea either. We could not argue that since post has higher precedence than pre, and since * and ++ associates from left to right, you are thinking that it would happen like this:

```
p1++;
++(*p1);
```

but it could happen the other way `++(*p1)` followed by `p1++`. The string could be modified and the string would become

> "libo"

because ++ just says that the increment happens later, not that it happens immediately.

Comment: Actually it is not! Read about operator preceedence.

Comment: `p` and `*p` are separate objects.

Comment: p points to string literal and *p to first position in that string literal. I know

Comment: You're not modifying the same object; the postfix operator advances the pointer, while the prefix operator increments the thing it's pointing *to*.

Comment: if p points to whole string literal increment p++ would make it point out of bound but in my computer it incrementing by 1byte I am getting output http://picpaste.com/post-PrDLkB6v.png

Comment: @RaghibAhsan: no, `p++` advances to the next character in the string, not to the end of the literal.  The type of `p` is `char *`, not `char (*)[5]`.